# Phabricator - group commits and audits

Tags: phabricator

We installed Phabricator as a POC. We have herald rules so that each commit requires an audit. We don't want to use differential, since this blocks commits.

The problems are:

1. If I had 2 audits for the same file from 2 different revisions, how can I make a link to the last audit/group for all of them?
2. How can I look at a diff range between multiple revision of the same file?

If we are using Phabricator incorrectly, please let us know what the best practices are?

Thanks

Comment: This is a highly unorthodox use of Audit.
1) I would presume 2 commits to the same file to have different code changes, and both should be reviewed.
2) There is no current functionality in Phabricator for this.

The point of Differential isn't to "block" commits. It has never slowed any team down that I've worked with. The point is that code should be reviewed for architectural reasons, that pre commit review lessens "fixing" things later because they're done with forethought the first time.

Comment: In contrast to @ChadLittle's statement, using differentials for pre-commit code review did slow my team as we learned it.  However, once people began to understand the process, there was a lot less time spent correcting issues.  Since the code wasn't on a branch for other developers to pull in until it had been reviewed, other developers weren't pulling in bad code to base their commits from.  It really sounds like pre-commit will do what you want and I strongly encourage you to give it a chance.

Comment: what you are suggesting is to move to differential? if so why should i use Audit ? what should i do in case i cannot make "block" on the svn , because we dont have permissions, all of this is handled on other internal system?

Comment: how can i enforce people to use differential?  what i mean is , from what i have read, you should use arc for creating differential.  anyway, if they will not use arc there is no way i can ever look and know they have changed the code and created a differential. 
so how can i do that ?

Comment: We use Audit when code is committed without reviews (urgent scenarios). Other teams use Audit for regulatory needs (multiple reviews) or spot checks (JS gurus). Basically, auditing.

You can force code reviews through Herald if your repository is hosted by Phabricator, otherwise you can use Herald to trigger Audits if code hasn't been pre-reviewed.

Using Differential without arc is something we do have planned, but no ETA right now. arc had lots of nice workflow features (like lint and unit) that reduce code review time, so it is recommended.

Comment: thank you very much @ChadLittle i will try to introduce it to my team. i hope they will love it and it would be usefull for us. even though working without arc maybe would be better.

Comment: @ChadLittle can you please attach screenshot of how to implement Herald Rule that will open Audit if there is no differential. please put as an answer, so i can solve this question and give you some reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Global Herald Rule on all Commits, have it match all commits that have no Differential Revision, and the action to Audit Commit by [Whatever Project Team] you want.